# error: invalid conversion from 'bottom**' to 'lefta**'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile and run this program .obviously, it doesn't work!my question is  why it is invalid conversion from bottom** to lefta** while bottom* can convert into lefta* ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class top
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    top(int b):a(b){}
    virtual void output(){cout<<a<<endl;}
};
class lefta:virtual public top
{
private:
    int b;
public:
    lefta(int c,int d):top(c),b(d){}
    void output(){cout<<b<<endl;}
};
class righta:virtual public top
{
private:
    int c;
public:
    righta(int c,int d):top(c),c(d){}
    void output(){cout<<c<<endl;}
};
class bottom:public lefta,public righta
{
private:
    int d;
public:
    bottom(int e,int f,int g,int h):top(e),lefta(e,f),righta(e,g),d(h){}
    void output(){cout<<d<<endl;}
};
int main()
{
    bottom* bo=new bottom(1,2,3,4);
//  lefta* le=bo;
//  le->output();
    bottom** p_bo=&bo;//here
    lefta** p_le=p_bo;//here
    (*p_le)->output();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Because they're not related at that level of indirection. You shouldn't have pointers to pointers anyway.

Comment: The better question is, _why do you think_ that just because `bottom*` can convert to `lefta*`, the same should magically be true for `bottom**` to `lefta**`?

Comment: Seriously related is [an oft-asked question about `T**` -> `const T**` conversions](http://kera.name/articles/2009/12/a-question-on-indirect-constness/).

Comment: Code is easier for other people to read if you add some spaces. Like `top(e), lefta(e, f), righta(e, g), d(h)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class leftb : public lefta { /* blah */ };

bottom* bo = new bottom(1,2,3,4);
bottom** p_bo = &bo;
lefta** p_le = p_bo;// let's pretend it works
// now p_le points to the variable bo, which is of type bottom*
// so *p_le is a reference to the variable bo
*p_le = new leftb(1,2); // wait, did we just assign a leftb* to a bottom*?
// (and yeah, I'm leaking memory. Sue me)
// bo now points to a leftb, but it is a bottom*
// oops, we just broke the type system
```

Comment: +1 for demonstration. And in general, the fact that `X` converts to `Y` doesn't mean `X*` can convert to `Y*`. This question is about the case `X = bottom*, Y = lefta*`, but for a more obvious situation that just won't work, consider `X = float, Y = double`. Converting a float to a double is easy enough, but converting a `float*` to `double*` is nonsense. The types aren't even the same size, let alone the question of what it would mean to store a `double` value (that might not be in the range of `float`) to the address previously held in the `float*`. The latter is the problem for `lefta*`.